# Regular expression to find and trim (leading and trailing whitespace) first column

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

For a tab-delimited table I would like to retrieve the first column of each row using a JavaScript regular expression. I would like to not include leading and trailing whitespace. If the column is empty (or just contains whitespace), I'd like to ignore it.

This is possible using bracketed sub-expressions:

```
/^ *((?=\S)[\S ]*\S) *(\t.*)*$/gm
```

So `$1` would give me what I want in this case. But I was wondering if there was a neater solution where the whole regular expression would match.

**Edit:** So for some example text:

```
abaft\tinfamous\tvase
  drab\tmarble
    \tcover\tmakeshift
skirt abrupt
```

The matches would be `abaft`, `drab` and `skirt abrupt`.

Comment: Example Please... [ask] & **[mcve]**

Comment: Instead of regex, use [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) to remove leading & trailing spaces from a string.

Comment: Please provide an example of your table.

Comment: Example included... apologies, I intended to but forgot.

Comment: Well, you could just use [`/^ *(\S[^\t]*)/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/tLiJzd/2) and grab Group 1 contents. What do you mean by *where the whole regular expression would match*? Without capturing?

Comment: Maybe `^\s*([^\\]*)`... [Here at regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/1yDXjY/2)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can use

```
/^ *(\S[^\t]*)/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tLiJzd/2) where your required values are captured into Group 1.

```js
var regex = /^ *(\S[^\t]*)/gm;
var str = "abaft infamous\tvase\n  drab marble\n     cover makeshift\nskirt abrupt";
var res = [];
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

*Details*:

- `^` -  matches start of a line (due to `/m` modifier)
- `*` - zero or more spaces
- `(\S[^\t]*)` - Goup 1 capturing

  - `\S` - a non-whitespace char
  - `[^\t]*` - zero or more chars other than a tab.

A variation of the same regex with `trim()` and `String#match`:

```js
var regex = /^ *\S[^\t]*/gm;
var str = "abaft infamous\tvase\n  drab marble\n     cover makeshift\nskirt abrupt";
var res = str.match(regex).map(function(x) {return x.trim();});
console.log(res);
```